# Computer slows down when plugged in

Tags: charging, cpu-speed

Recently, whenever I plug in my laptop, the CPU slows down severely. Also, it isn't charging, as it says "plugged in, not charging". The CPU drops from 2200 Mhz, to 500 Mhz. I've changed the advanced power plan settings.
My laptop is a Dell Inspiron 15 7000 Series

Edit - I'm on Windows 10 and don't use any software for power management, and other  chargers don't help either. I have been using the original Dell charger

Comment: OS? Version? Any software for power management used? How is your issue different to https://superuser.com/questions/319684/dell-inspiron-1545-plugged-in-not-charging or https://superuser.com/questions/885415/hp-4530s-laptop-works-with-power-cord-but-wont-charge-battery Have you tried another charger?

Comment: "Plugged in, not charging" usually indicates a battery problem - as in the battery is toast, and not accepting a charge.

Comment: i have tried another charger, but it doesn't work. I think the battery might be gone. This in itself isn't a problem, as i don't use it very often, but the laptop slows down a lot when plugged in, and becomes near impossible to use. @ssice

Comment: Try running it plugged in with the battery removed.

Answer (score 0):

So this isn't a fix to the "not charging" problem, but I installed ThrottleStop, and switched off BD PROCHOT, and this fixes the slowing down of the CPU, which was my main problem, and as far as I can tell, the laptop isn't overheating.